# Node, Express, Jade dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

My code is below: The question is:

**How do I make it so that my jade file will render a description of the event based on the value of the select menu? Basically if the select option has a value of 1 then p should render p #{event[1].description}.**

considering Jade precompiles I don't have access to the DOM which eliminates  `document.getElementbyId("test").selectedIndex;` Below is my attempt at solving it on server side. I think I am missing something though because to me no matter the approach I will need access to the DOM to see the value change in the select menu to spit out the "event description".

Any help would be appreciated.

**Jade File**

```
    extends layout

block content

    form(role='form', action="/doSomthing", method="post")
      select#test.form-control(name = "choices")
        each events, i in event
         option(value=i) #{events.event}
      button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
      &nbsp; 
      a(href='/')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type="button") Cancel
      
    p#{events[0].description} //I want to pass an array instead of explicitly  calling [0]
```

**Route**

```
router.get('/eventreg', function(req, res) {
    var ei = event.eventid;
    var eiarray = Event.findOne({'eventid': cc });
    
    Event.find({}, function(err, event){
        res.render('eventreg', {user : req.user, event: event});
        console.log(event);
        console.log(eiarray);
    });
});
```

My thought was that I could create the looping array on server side so it would compile, but once the page has rendered and I change the selected option value it wouldn't recompile again on the fly.

Would React solve this problem? It seems like a bit overkill.

Thank you again for your time everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a piece of JavaScript to your page that then does the desired text changes in the browser. Add something like this to the bottom of your Jade page:

```
script.
  $('#theOptionField').on('change', function(e) {
    // get value that the user selected
    // modify the HTML of the element that should display the value
  });
```